# Database won't be deleted

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have a database but before I want to add data, I want to clear it:

```
private Cursor getAllPlayers(){


    try {
        playerDatabase.beginTransaction();
        playerDatabase.delete (PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.TABLE_NAME,null,null);
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        //Something
    }
    finally {
        playerDatabase.endTransaction();
    }
    playerDatabase = ComposeMessage.addPlayerToTheDatabase(playerDatabase, playerDataSet);
    return playerDatabase.query(PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            null,null,null,
            null,null, PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.COLUMN_PLAYER_NAME);
}
```

But the table won't be cleared, I check via sqlite3 on the terminal via shell on the emulator and can see that the data just keeps being added and the row number is increasing.

The table:

```
public static final class PlayerTableEntry implements BaseColumns{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "playerTable";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLAYER_NAME = "playerName";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLAYER_NUMBER = "playerNumber";
    public static final String COLUMN_IS_PLAYING = "isPlaying";
}
```

Not sure what I am missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't understand why its not working. Can you try with below code.

```
public void deleteAllRow(String value){      
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME+ ");
}
```

Comment: This does work! Thanks but I must ask...how and why??

Comment: I am also thinking the same.

Comment: Please check previous method gives any `Exception`. I mean log the exception.